# Repeated author in bibliography - mark author as female

Tags: biblatex, biber, polish

When using footcite for another book by the same author as previous citation in polish we use *tenże* (the same man as above) or *taż* (the same **woman** as above). Latex inserts *tenże* for both men and women authors.

Is it possible to let latex know gender of author? Or how to solve that problem otherwise?

My example:
bib:

```
@book{      kowalska1,
author =    {J. Kowalska},
title =     {Jeden},
location =  {Warszawa},
year =      {2003}
}
@book{      kowalska2,
author =    {J. Kowalska},
title =     {Dwa},
location =  {Kraków},
year =      {2008}
}
```

tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{csquotes}
\DeclareQuoteStyle[quotes]{polish}
  {\quotedblbase}
  {\textquotedblright}
  [0.05em]
  {\quotesinglbase}
  {\fixligatures\textquoteright}
\DeclareQuoteAlias[quotes]{polish}{polish}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{polish} 
\setotherlanguage{russian}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text, Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\russianfont[Script=Cyrillic]{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage[
  style=verbose-trad1, % numeric, alphabetic, authoryear, ect.
  sorting=nty,
  isbn=false,
backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliografia.bib}
\begin{document}
Lorem \footcite{kowalska1} 
ipsum \footcite{kowalska2}.
Lorem \footcite{kowalska1} 
ipsum \footcite{kowalska2}.
\end{document}
```

latex output:
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should have searched for for example "gender" or "female" in the Biblatex documentation.

With

```
@book{      kowalska1,
author =    {J. Kowalska},
gender =    {sf},
title =     {Jeden},
location =  {Warszawa},
year =      {2003}
}
```

you get "Taż sama, Jeden." The argument "sf" means "single female". See the documentation for other options.

Comment: Thank you very much! Next time I'll start with documentation. This time I've looked into google and there query like "latex female" is not very helpful :)

Comment: To begin with you have to realize that the relevant system you are using is Biblatex.  Asking if it is possible to let *latex* know the gender or thinking of googling for "latex" instead of "biblatex" won't help you.